# Conditional Regex statements

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a Regex that validates a phone number to make sure it starts from 0700 - 0792.
I initially had a Rex to validate from 0700 - 0789 which was:

```
/^07[0-8][0-9]/
```

And now I dont know how to modify it to have it in such a way that if the 3rd digit is 9 then it should only allow the 4th digit to be only 0,1 or 2.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to,

```
/^07(?:[0-8][0-9]|9[012])/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^07(?:[0-8][0-9]|9[0-2])$
```

You can `or` the extra `3` numbers.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/14